# Print to Excel file instead of PDF in SAP ERP

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, export-to-excel, sap-erp

I have the transaction `ZHR_TM01` in SAP ERP (built by our IT department) that prints the timesheets of our employees that are swiping a card.

I need all this data in excel format but the problem is that the only option I know is to type `"PDF!"` in the command bar when I'm on the print preview menu of the timesheet, so it will convert all selected timesheets to pdf format. In order to have this data in excel format I need to use acrobat converter. This option is somewhat unprofessional and working with the sheet becomes very "convert dependent" because every time I use this method the conversion is slightly different compared to previous conversions: the columns/rows are not consistent etc.

What I ask is is there a way to directly retrieve the data in some readable **consistent** format since it is obvious that the data exists.

If there is a analogous command like the PDF! to convert to excel format or any other?

It will help me big time.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If the function code `PDF!` works, the printout is most likely implemented using a Smart Form. In this case, it should be possible to create an alternative download function, e. g. SALV. I'd recommend contacting the person who originally developed the transaction to get an estimate - I'm not qualified to get into the details of HR...

Answer (score 0):

See if you can convert to a .csv or .txt file. Once you have it in either of those formats you should be able to import them into Excel and delimit the columns with greater accuracy.